# OptInRequired Error when trying to init AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I just started using AWS Amplify. I've installed and configured the CLI and I'm trying to initialize a project. However, after making the selections I get the following error:

```
Edwards-MacBook-Air:amplify-js-app edward$ amplify init
Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory
? Enter a name for the project amplify-js-app
? Enter a name for the environment env
? Choose your default editor: Visual Studio Code
? Choose the type of app that you're building javascript
Please tell us about your project
? What javascript framework are you using none
? Source Directory Path:  src
? Distribution Directory Path: dist
? Build Command:  npm run-script build
? Start Command: npm run-script start
Using default provider  awscloudformation

For more information on AWS Profiles, see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

? Do you want to use an AWS profile? Yes
? Please choose the profile you want to use default
⠧ Initializing project in the cloud...An error occurred when creating the CloudFormation stack
✖ Root stack creation failed
init failed
{ OptInRequired: The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service
    at Request.extractError (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/edward/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message: 'The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service',
  code: 'OptInRequired',
  time: 2019-03-03T21:14:34.638Z,
  requestId: '581c6e4a-3df9-11e9-8269-59b4c2d8d7d2',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 21.790819558046604 }
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is usually related to a new account, an updated payment method, or something like an unverified phone number. Login to the console and make sure you don't have any notifications or alerts. If you don't see anything I suggest calling AWS billing.